# What is required for transatlantic flight in a private plane?

Tags: equipment, visual-flight-rules, transatlantic

What equipment is required to fly a small plane across the Atlantic via Canada, Greenland, and Iceland? Is any additional training required beyond an ordinary pilot certificate? Can it be done in VFR flight?

Comment: Detailed knowledge of geography, airports where you can land along the way etc. I am not an expert but these things came to my mind.

Comment: how about "enough fuel!"

Comment: True. In fact, for flights leaving Canada you are required to have 10% more fuel than the normal IFR requirements.

Answer (score 9):

While probably legal to fly over the Atlantic VFR, it appears getting out of Canadas airspace is a different matter. After a bit of googling I found [this article](http://www.copanational.org/CC-42.cfm) on COPA's website, saying:

> Both for flying in the northern parts of Canada as well as in
>   Greenland airspace, an ADF is legally required (refer to TC AIM
>   3.16.10 and CAR 605.18). I didn’t have one, so one had to be installed. Other than that, FDOW didn’t need any modifications. IFR
>   approved GPS is an absolute must; we had three GPS receivers on board.
>
> Speaking of IFR: As per CAR 602.19, pilots attempting trans-oceanic
>   flight must hold an instrument rating. Even though an IFR flight plan
>   is only required above 5,500 feet across the Atlantic, NavCanada will
>   not issue an oceanic VFR clearance when leaving Canada. In addition,
>   it is extremely unlikely for any airplane to stay in VMC during the
>   whole trans-Atlantic flight. Therefore, it’s mandatory that both,
>   pilot and airplane are certified and current IFR.

That being said, weather over the Atlantic can be very treacherous, especially if you're unable to climb on top.

There are quite a few stories around about crossing the Atlantic in smaller airplanes, there's also an [Ice Pilots NWT episode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ice_Pilots_NWT_episodes) (season 1 episode 9) where they ferry two water-bombers to Turkey, although not very technical, it's a nice watch.

Answer (score 6):

I did a crossing in a Beech Bonanza in mid-july; even during that month I picked up ice. I wouldn't cross VFR unless you had a lot of time sitting around iceland waiting for a large high pressure system to stumble your way. As an example faroe was clear when I arrived and the control folks said the sky hadn't been clear in 20,days; so I got a nice clear day of sight seeing. Bergen was socked in IFR with ice, so I was delayed even having IMC capable plane and CMEL-IR... The weather systems are smaller up north, and they tend to linger it seems.

Comment: What kind of icing? Induction, instrument, or structural?